# Packages R Azure Machine Learning

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm new in Azure and I would like to run my R Code, I read how it's work but I have problem to run my packages but I always get errors like this .

> package 'ParamHelpers' required by 'mlr' could not be found

And when I run in Rstudio i don't have the same errors

I have a zip file with inside the zip packages

```
install.packages("src/Metrics_0.1.1.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/checkmate_1.7.0.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/mlr_2.7.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/xgboost_0.4-2.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
install.packages("src/BBmisc_1.9.zip", lib = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = TRUE)

library(xgboost)
library(Metrics, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
library(checkmate, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
library(BBmisc, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
library(mlr, lib.loc=".", verbose=TRUE)
library(Hmisc)
packageVersion("mlr")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add all the packages to your zip-file that mlr needs. Both BBmisc and ParamHelpers are not available on Azure, so you need to add these to the zip-file containing the other packages like mlr.

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-extend-your-experiment-with-r/) is a list of available packages in Azure ML .

and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html) is the overview of packages mlr depends on and suggests

Comment: Thanks, for your answer I don't really know which packages MLR use, each time i need to see the errors and update a new zip file ...

Answer (score -1):

You can try this - http://gallery.azureml.net/Details/7507f907deb845d9b9b193b455a8615d

The above link shows a simple model for predicting acceptance to graduate school using xgboost library and serializing model into data.frame